# Code executing else statement, then if statement. (JS)

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a simple code but for some reason, I have an if statement, then an else statement. The code satisfies both the if and the else statment but it should only execute the if statment. Heres the problematic code:

```js
var z;
var zr;
var zx;
function t(a,b,c) {
if (b == null) { //this should executes and does
b = (180-a)/2
c = t(a,b)
t2(a,b,c)
    zx = z + " " + zr
console.log("Triangle type is:" + zx + "Angle B is " + b + ". Angle C is " + c)
return b
}
else {  //this else should not execute yet does
console.log("hi##") //debug stuffs 
if (c == null) {
        console.log("#hi") //more debugs stuffs
        c = 180 - (a+b)
        t2(a,b,c)
        zx = z + " " + zr
        console.log("Triangle type is: " + zx + ". Angle C is " + c) 
        console.log("#bye") //even more debug stuffs
        return c
    
    }
```

Input t(60)
Heres the output:

hi##

#hi

Triangle type is: equiangular Equilateral. Angle C is 60

#bye

Triangle type is:equiangular EquilateralAngle B is 60. Angle C is 60

60

So you can see my problem. Attched is the full code to help figure out my problem.

```js
var z;
var zr;
var zx;
function t(a,b,c) {
if (b == null) {
b = (180-a)/2
c = t(a,b)
t2(a,b,c)
    zx = z + " " + zr
console.log("Triangle type is:" + zx + "Angle B is " + b + ". Angle C is " + c)
return b
}
else {  
console.log("hi##")
if (c == null) {
        console.log("#hi")
        c = 180 - (a+b)
        t2(a,b,c)
        zx = z + " " + zr
        console.log("Triangle type is: " + zx + ". Angle C is " + c) 
        console.log("#bye")
        return c
    
    }
    else {
        x = 180 - (a+b+c)
        if (x == 0) {
            t2(a,b,c)
            zx = z + " " + zr
           console.log("Can be triangle. Triangle type is: " + zx)
            
            return x
          }
        else {
           
if (x>0) {
            console.log("Cannot be a triangle needs " + x + " more")
return x
}
            else {
                console.log("Cannot be a triangle needs " + Math.abs(x) + " less")
return x
            }
        }
    }
}
}
function t2(a,b,c) {
    r = ""
    //triangle.angletype: 
    if (a == 90|b == 90|c == 90) {
        z = "Right" 
        t3(a,b,c)
    }
    else if (a > 90| b > 90| c > 90) {
        z = "Obtuse"
        t3(a,b,c)
    }
    else if (a == 60 && b == 60 && c == 60) {
        z = "equiangular"
        t3(a,b,c)
    }
    else if (a < 90 || b < 90 || c < 90) {
        z = "Acute"
        t3(a,b,c)
    }
    else {
        throw new Error("Unable to determine triangle angletype \n operation triangle.angletype")
    }
}
function t3(a,b,c) {
if (a != b && a != c && b != c) {
    zr = "Scalene"
}
else if (a == b && a == c && a == c) {
    zr = "Equilateral"
}
else if (a == b || b == c || a == c) {
        zr = "Isosceles"
    }
else {
throw new Error("Unable to determine triangle name \n operation triangle.name")
}
}
```

If anybody can give me guidence that would be wonderful. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` statements are working as you expect. What might be confusing you is that you're calling the first function `t(a,b,c)` again inside the `if` block:

```
if (b == null) {
...
c = t(a,b) // here
...
}
```

it's not clear what that `t(a,b,c)` is meant to return, but I suspect this line of code could be removed, and you could change the line above it to be `b = c = (180-a)/2` and you would get behaviour similar to what you expect:

```js
var z;
var zr;
var zx;
function t(a, b, c) {
  if (b == null) {
    b = c = (180 - a) / 2; // modified this line to also set c
    // c = t(a, b); // removed this line
    t2(a, b, c);
    zx = z + " " + zr;
    console.log(
      "Triangle type is:" + zx + "Angle B is " + b + ". Angle C is " + c
    );
    return b;
  } else {
    console.log("hi##");
    if (c == null) {
      console.log("#hi");
      c = 180 - (a + b);
      t2(a, b, c);
      zx = z + " " + zr;
      console.log("Triangle type is: " + zx + ". Angle C is " + c);
      console.log("#bye");
      return c;
    } else {
      x = 180 - (a + b + c);
      if (x == 0) {
        t2(a, b, c);
        zx = z + " " + zr;
        console.log("Can be triangle. Triangle type is: " + zx);

        return x;
      } else {
        if (x > 0) {
          console.log("Cannot be a triangle needs " + x + " more");
          return x;
        } else {
          console.log("Cannot be a triangle needs " + Math.abs(x) + " less");
          return x;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
function t2(a, b, c) {
  r = "";
  //triangle.angletype:
  if ((a == 90) | (b == 90) | (c == 90)) {
    z = "Right";
    t3(a, b, c);
  } else if ((a > 90) | (b > 90) | (c > 90)) {
    z = "Obtuse";
    t3(a, b, c);
  } else if (a == 60 && b == 60 && c == 60) {
    z = "equiangular";
    t3(a, b, c);
  } else if (a < 90 || b < 90 || c < 90) {
    z = "Acute";
    t3(a, b, c);
  } else {
    throw new Error(
      "Unable to determine triangle angletype \n operation triangle.angletype"
    );
  }
}
function t3(a, b, c) {
  if (a != b && a != c && b != c) {
    zr = "Scalene";
  } else if (a == b && a == c && a == c) {
    zr = "Equilateral";
  } else if (a == b || b == c || a == c) {
    zr = "Isosceles";
  } else {
    throw new Error(
      "Unable to determine triangle name \n operation triangle.name"
    );
  }
}

t(60);
```